# Too many dynamic script compilations within, max: [75/5m]

Tags: elasticsearch-6

I am getting below error in elasticsearch.

`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"circuit_breaking_exception","reason":"[script] Too many dynamic script compilations within, max: [75/5m]; please use indexed, or scripts with parameters instead; this limit can be changed by the [script.max_compilations_rate] setting","bytes_wanted":0,"bytes_limit":0}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"en_product_idx2","node":"eFSrhLqNTYubukyF3pz8aw","reason":{"type":"query_shard_exception","reason":"script_score: the script could not be loaded","index_uuid":"IFYbHBBjRxW188SKVh0c4Q","index":"en_product_idx2","caused_by":{"type":"general_script_exception","reason":"Failed to compile inline script [if (params['_source']['sku'] == \"black\") return 999; else return 434-params.ids.indexOf(doc['id'].value.intValue());] using lang [painless]","caused_by":{"type":"circuit_breaking_exception","reason":"[script] Too many dynamic script compilations within, max: [75/5m]; please use indexed, or scripts with parameters instead; this limit can be changed by the [script.max_compilations_rate] setting","bytes_wanted":0,"bytes_limit":0}}}}],"caused_by":{"type":"circuit_breaking_exception","reason":"[script] Too many dynamic script compilations within, max: [75/5m]; please use indexed, or scripts with parameters instead; this limit can be changed by the [script.max_compilations_rate] setting","bytes_wanted":0,"bytes_limit":0}},"status":400}`

Comment: And I fixed this using below command and thought to share here so that anyone can use the same approach.

Comment: curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_cluster/settings" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{ "transient": { "script.max_compilations_rate": "30/1m"}}'

Comment: your solution worked for me, many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

@anjanbarik solution is correct, I don't want to take away merit..
But instead of "transient" it's better to use "persistent", if not the changes will be gone after a full cluster restart.

You can use any of the below requests to apply the changes:

- **Using curl:**
  `curl -X PUT "localhost:9200/_cluster/settings" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{ "persistent": {"script.max_compilations_rate": "200/10m"}}'`
- **Using Dev Console:**

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
    "persistent" : {
        "script.max_compilations_rate" : "200/10m"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the above worked for me using ES version 7.*

Answer (score 1):

Scripting is not normal behavior, because the script needs to be compiled, there is a limit on the number of inline script compilations within a period of time.

[Script compilation circuit breaker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/circuit-breaker.html#script-compilation-circuit-breaker)

You can follow the "prefer-parameters" section of the [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-using.html#prefer-params) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

## parameterize the script

- https://web.archive.org/web/20180720053231/https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html#prefer-params

My issue was that I neglected to parameterize my script properly and was interpolating a list into the script:

broken script manually injecting the `prop_groups` into the script:

```
if (doc.containsKey('prop_groups') && doc['prop_groups'].length > 0) {{
    int[] prop_groups = new int[] {{{', '.join([str(x) for x in prop_groups])}}}; 
    for(int i = 0; i < doc['prop_groups'].length; i++)
```

Fixed, using `params.prop_groups`:

```
if (doc.containsKey('prop_groups') && doc['prop_groups'].length > 0) {{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < doc['prop_groups'].length; i++) 
    {{
        for(int j = 0; j < params['prop_groups'].length; j++)
```

Passing in the params:

```
        return {
            "script": {
                "source": script,
                "params": {"prop_groups": [str(x) for x in prop_groups]},
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/_scripts/scriptnameupdate
```

Script with params as follows:

```
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
"source": "ctx._source.b_id=params.b_id;ctx._source.a_id=params.a_id;ctx._source.a_name=params.a_name;"
  }
}
```